# Rougher treks with Vibram Fivefingers

Tags: hiking, vibram-five-fingers

I hike quite a bit in Vibram Fivefinger Kimodo Sports.  Like the KSO, they are covered and don't have a problem with rocks getting in.  I strongly prefer them to boots for marked trails, and would like to find ways of using them for some moderate trail-less backcountry hiking.  How can I protect myself from scratches?  Will gaiters work, or wear out underfoot without the sole gap provided by boots?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When wearing my Vibrams, I tend to travel much more carefully than when wearing my trail runners, so I find that I need less protection than I would in more traditional footwear. I would say it depends a lot on the areas you'll be in. What do you mean by off trail? Forested areas, chaparral, flat land?

Comment: Forested, hardwood and pine..  Some things to scratch me, such as thorns and poison ivy in VA and pine branches in NY's Adirondacks.

Comment: I've never needed gaiters for anything like that. Are long pants not enough protection for you?

Comment: For much of the year, yes.  Pants in 105° is a no go. :-) I've also been pretty scratched up even with boots off trail, so I figure it would only be worse with 5-fingers.